# Controlling placement of footer sections on page in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I use CrystalReport in Visual Studio 2005 and make a bill report ... this bill
I use the header - Details- and footer in this report ..
in details section I limit the record to 10 for every page 
so if there is a bill contains 15 record ..
first 10 record in first page . and 5 in the second page when print 
put the problems 
1- the footer show in the second page only 
2- in the second page the Fields in the footer Raised up beacuse the second page contains 5 records only 
so if the record number in the report is not 10 so the footer fields raised up 
so please any one help me to solve the problem 
Notation : I limit the number of records for every page to 10 record only .. i need empty 
records if the reports records < 10 \
Please any one help my 
Thanks

Comment: I'm unclear about your issue. Do you want the footer on every page but you're only seeing it once? Or do you want the footer to draw at the bottom of the page instead of just below the last detail? Or is the problem that some of your detail records aren't printing because of the way you're inserting page breaks?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know 100% what your problem is (maybe post some screenshots) but there might be two possible problems/solutions:

- in CR Reports you've got document and page footer - if you use the document footer (don't remember the exact name) you will see this only once - just like a document header
- if the details parts get's to big the footers are AFAIK the first thing that get's striped so try to compress your details (or any other section) to get more area for the footer (or display only 9 items per page instead of 10 - just for trial)

To really fill your report with empty details you will have to append *empty* rows to your data and use conditional *supresses* in your CR to not show things like '0' but IMHO this will get a real pain and you should go without printing empty details - never seen a situation where you need this or where it is desired.